# Why is Spring Boot (in Kotlin) always returning a status code of 200 no matter what?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

So I have this really simple code currently to try and get it to return the correct response code in my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
fun test() : Response
{
    try {
        privateMethod()
    } catch (e: ResponseStatusException) {
        return BadRequestResponse(e.message)
    }
    return ShowResponse(null)
}

private fun privateMethod() {
    throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
}
```

However, the server responds with a status code of 200 but returns the status code 401 in the message element in the response body.

I've tried this as well and it doesn't work either:

```
@PatchMapping("/shows")
fun shows(@RequestBody json: ShowJSON) : Response? {
    return try {
        ShowResponse(actionFactory.upsert(json))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        handleException(e)
    }
}

private fun handleException(e: Exception) : Response {
    if (e is BadRequestException) {
        return BadRequestResponse(e.message, e.errors)
    }
    else if (e is NoElementFoundException) {
        return NoElementFoundResponse()
    }

    return UnknownErrorResponse()
}

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
class BadRequestException(override val message: String, val errors: List<String> = listOf()) : Exception(message)
```

...and that still returns a status code of 200. Could there be something misconfigured in my app that always tells it to return a code of 200?

Comment: Its because you are catching the exception. Instead of catching just throw the exact exception you are getting to view the response code correctly.

Comment: is there a way to catch the exceptions and still return a different status code? i may want the response body to be different from the exception, also dont want stack trace  in there

Comment: Use `ResponseEntity` for that.

Comment: yes, that seemed to work for what i needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ResponseEntity was better suited for my needs. Basically I still catch the exceptions but use ResponseEntity to output the correct status code:

```
@PatchMapping("/shows")
fun shows(@RequestBody json: ShowJSON) : ResponseEntity<Response> {
    return try {
        ResponseEntity(ShowResponse(actionFactory.upsert(json)), HttpStatus.OK)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        handleException(e)
    }
}

private fun handleException(e: Exception) : ResponseEntity<Response> {
    if (e is BadRequestException) {
        return ResponseEntity(BadRequestResponse(e.message, e.errors), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    } else if (e is NoElementFoundException) {
        return ResponseEntity(NoElementFoundResponse(e.message, e.type, e.model_id), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    }

    return ResponseEntity(UnknownErrorResponse(), HttpStatus.OK)
}
```